# Printing non-Latin based characters in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Have anyone of you ever had the need to print a non-Latin character, such as Russian or Hebrew or Hindi, in Python and how did you go about doing it?
When I tried to do `print('ש')`, it simply printed a blank... Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible the shell you are invoking the script from can't display the character correctly?

Comment: yes. That's what it was. Thanks.